# Rust variable lifetime and Security

Tags: rust

I am having trouble understanding what is Rust protecting this program from:

```
fn foo() -> &i32 { 
    let x: i32 = 0;
    &x
}

fn main () {
    let p = foo();
    *p = 42 ; // attempt to store 42 at address p => error!
}
```

Why is there an error ? I understand that it is caused by local variable lifetime, what I don't understand is what common vulnerability is it protecting from ?

Is this system adopted by Rust made to protect against Use-after-free ? How is the C equivalent of this program Vulnerable ?

Comment: The `foo` function in your program will throw compilation errors as well.

Comment: Is it some syntax error in ```foo``` ?

Comment: Try it on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cccd94164642663f629864d0e02e7c6d)

Comment: It sounds like you're simply asking how a use-after-free is a vulnerability. [Have a look through the CVEs](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvekey.cgi?keyword=use+after+free). Even if a use-after-free doesn't have a known attack vector, it is considered a security vulnerability because the scope of effect is often unknown and thus could affect sensitive or critical data.

Comment: I know how use after free is dangerous. But how can rust protect against it by preventing us from ```*p = 42 ;```. Besides, there is no free here, so why can't I use my variable ?

Comment: *"there is no free here"* - the memory for `x` is reclaimed when `foo` returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, `x` is Dropped (https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Drop.html) at the end of the function `foo`.

```rust
fn foo() -> &i32 { 
    let x: i32 = 0;
    &x
} // <-- `x` is dropped (or freed) at this point

fn main () {
    let p = foo(); <-- `p` would be a pointer to an area of memory that has been freed if the compiler allowed this
    *p = 42 ; <-- this would set some arbitrary memory address to 42 if it was allowed
}
```

This is protecting you from assigning a value to a reference that no longer points to a valid memory location.